# Rails-React: passing a rendered jbuilder template to component props from controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, react-rails

Right now I have my index action set up like this, and I when the games component is rendered it basically receives `games.to_json`, I would like to reuse the template I have for `GET /games.json` which is specified in `views/games/index.json.builder`

I tried passing `render(template: 'games/index.json')` but I get this error:

Render and/or redirect were called multiple times in this action

```
def index
  @games = Game.all
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render component: 'games', props: { games: @games } }
    format.json { render :index }
  end
end
```

On `views/games/index.json.jbuilder`

```
json.array! @games do |game|
  json.extract! game, :id, :title, :cover_thumbnail
  json.url game_url(game, format: :json)
end
```

If I call `GET /games.json` I get something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": 133,
    "title": "Final Fantasy VII: Remake",
    "coverThumbnail": "url",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/games/133.json"
  },
  ...
]
```

But when I call `GET /games`, the games component receives every single attribute, I want to send only the attributes specified on the jbuilder template

Comment: Did you place the code inside the format.json brackets? `format.json{ <----- place your rendering here ------>   }`

Comment: Yes, I tried `props: { games: render(template: 'games/index') }` but I get the double render error. The problem is rendering the html, not the json